# flex Start Conditions (matching string literals)

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I'm implementing the start condition for matching C-style strings in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html).

The segment I'm concerned with is:

```
     <str>\"        { /* saw closing quote - all done */
             BEGIN(INITIAL);
             *string_buf_ptr = '\0';
             /* return string constant token type and
              * value to parser
              */
             }
```

I have no issue returning the token type, but I'm unsure how to pass the string value in this situation. If I print yytext when the token is returned, it's simply holding the " terminator.

So how would I get the string's value?

Thanks in advance; I'm new to flex.

Comment: Isn't the value in string_buf_ptr?  Just copy it to yylval (or use it directly if reentrancy isn't a problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not return `yytext` but you return a pointer to `string_buf`.

`yytext` contains the terminator because that is the content of the last regular expression for the matched state. In all other cases (but the terminator) of your example, the content of `yytext` is copied to `string_buf` (e.g. check the lines with `*string_buf_ptr++=*yptr++;`), so that buffer holds the final string.